Prove that for $F$ an additive functor of abelian categories, $R^0F$ is exact iff $R^1F = 0$ iff $R^iF = 0$ for all $i > 0$
I am beginning to study homological algebra. Let $F: \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ be an additive functor of abelian categories. Prove that the following are equivalent:

The functor $R^0F$ is exact
$R^1F = 0$
$R^iF = 0$ for all $i > 0$

I am thinking about proving $(3) \implies (2) \implies (1) \implies (3)$. We see that clearly $(3) \implies (2)$. I am wondering if it was intended that the functor $F$ is an left exact functor, since the notion of right derived functor is normally defined only for left exact additive functors on an abelian category with enough injectives. I was wondering if you could provide input for this. In other words, do we need to assume that $F$ is left exact and that $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives to answer this question?
Here is what I have so far, assuming that $F$ indeed is a left exact additive functor on an abelian category with enough injectives. $(2) \to (1)$: let $0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0$ be an exact sequence. Then by applying $F$ to injective resolutions of $A,B$, and $C$, we have a long exact sequence
$$0 \to R^0F(A) \to R^0F(B) \to R^0F(C) \to R^1F(A) = 0 \to R^1F(B) = 0 \to \cdots$$
so that $R^0F$ is exact. $(1) \implies (3)$: Since $F$ is left exact, $R^0F \cong F$, so that $F$ preserves exact sequences, and in particular the exactness of injective resolutions associated with $A,B,$ and $C$. By definition of $R^iF$ as the cohomology (i.e. the cokernel of $Im(F(d_{i-1})) \to \ker(F(d_i))$) and by the fact that $F$ preserves exactness of injective resolutions, we have that $R^iF = 0$ for all $i > 0$.
I am wondering (i) whether the above proof of mine is correct, and (ii) whether the question makes sense without assuming that $F$ is left exact and $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives, and if so how to prove the same question in its original form.

I'm not an expert, but as far as I know, I agree that you should assume that $F$ is left exact and $A$ has enough injectives, and your argument looks fine to me. You can also prove $1 \Rightarrow 3$ using only the long exact sequence.

Your proof is fine. Definitely we should assume something to be confident the derived functor even exists, so assume enough injectives. We don't always need $F$ to be left exact. Sometimes yes, sometimes no. $R^0F$ is always left exact; it would suffice to understand $R^\ast(R^0F)\cong R^\ast F$. Fix $A$, injectively resolve $A\hookrightarrow I^\ast$. We want to compare the cohomologies of $0\to FI^0\to FI^1\to\cdots$ with $0\to R^0FI^0\to R^0FI^1\to\cdots$. But of course, $R^0F$ and $F$ agree on injectives (up to natural isomorphisms, if you like) so the claim is immediate. Now if $R^0F$ is exact, $R^\ast(R^0F)$ vanishes in positive degree... but that's just $R^\ast F$.

thank you. why does it suffice to show that $R^* (F^0F) \cong R^* F$? Also, why does $R^0F$ and $F$ agree on injectives?

Because you could use the demonstration for the left exact case to say $R^\ast(R^0F)$ vanishes in positive degree, and then use $R^\ast(R^0F)\cong R^\ast F$ to get that $R^\ast F$ vanishes in positive degree. As for why $R^0F\cong F$ (naturally!) when restricted to the subcategory of injectives? Just think about the definition. What's an injective resolution of an injective object $J$? Well, $0\to J=J\to0$ works doesn't it.. and a map of objects $J\to J'$ makes a clear map of such resolutions, so $R^0F$ is the zeroth cohomology functor for $F(0\to J\to0\to0\to\cdots)$ i.e. just $F$
